# Trying To Understand the Difference Between Synchronous and Asynchronous Network Calls

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure how I can make an asynchronous network call in the same way that I am doing a synchronous call. I want to understand the difference with regards to a certain network call I am trying to make.

This is the synchronous network call I made:

```
func fetchTrendingMoviesSynchronous() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.trakt.tv/movies/trending") else {
        print("Could not get trending movies.")
        return
    }
        
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("2", forHTTPHeaderField: "trakt-api-version")
    request.addValue("My_API_Key", forHTTPHeaderField: "trakt-api-key")
                
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if response != nil {
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([TrendingMovie].self, from: data!) {
                print("We got the trending movies.")
                trendingMovies = decodedResponse
            }
        } else {
            print("Could not get trending movies.")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

My main issue is trying to figure out how to call addValue properly in the asynchronous network call.

This is what I have so far for the asynchronous call:

```
func fetchTrendingMoviesAsynchronous() async {
        
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.trakt.tv/movies/trending") else {
        print("Could not get trending movies.")
        return
    }
        
    do {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
        if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([TrendingMovie].self, from: data) {
            print("We got the trending movies.")
            trendingMovies = decodedResponse
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not get trending movies.")
    }
}
```

How would I go about making the asynchronous call work with regards to including `addValue`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first example is asynchronous, too.

Comment: @vadian Could you explain how it is? I'm still new to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.data(for: URLRequest)` in order to add headers.

```
    func fetchTrendingMoviesAsynchronous() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.trakt.tv/movies/trending") else {
            print("Could not get trending movies.")
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("2", forHTTPHeaderField: "trakt-api-version")
        request.addValue("My_API_Key", forHTTPHeaderField: "trakt-api-key")
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([TrendingMovie].self, from: data) {
                print("We got the trending movies.")
                trendingMovies = decodedResponse
            }
        }catch {
            print("Could not get trending movies.")
        }
    }
```